# "Diameter is" versus "Diameters are"

Tags: grammaticality, grammatical-number, verb-agreement

Which one is correct?

1. In [7] the **diameter** of Cayley graphs on *S<sub>n</sub>* **is** calculated.
2. In [7] the **diameters** of Cayley graphs on *S<sub>n</sub>*  **are** calculated.

Comment: For each *n*, does [7] calculate the diameter of a single canonical Cayley graph on *S_n*, the diameters of some of the Cayley graphs on *S_n,* or the diameter of all of the Cayley graphs on *S_n*? Depending on which it is, it should be *the diameter of the Cayley graph on S_n*, *the diameters of Cayley graphs on S_n*, or *the diameters of the Cayley graphs on S_n*?

Answer (score 1):

How many different diameters are there?

If all the diameters are the same, then it's *diameter* and *is* (because there is only one); if there are a number of different diameters, then use the plural sentence.

Or: since you are measuring a single property of a set, you can use *diameter is*.

Either is possible and would be understood. But since we don't know what [7] is, it's difficult to say which is to be preferred, if any.